# Does Hinduism offer solution for each and every problem of human life?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, practice

Like many other I expect Hinduism suggest a way to  live life. Is it true? Can we interpret that it also means there are solutions in Hinduism to every problem one can encounter?

Comment: Yes it does. And AFAIK a problem can not exist alone too. It has to coexist with its respective solution.

Comment: @Rickross are such problem and solutions discussed here?

Comment: "are such problem and solutions discussed here?" Depends. Go ahead and ask.

Comment: @@Creator.. Of course not. The total number of such  "problems" must be very large .

Comment: Hinduism may not give you solutions to each and every problem. It gives you a way to go ahead and find solutions on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism is all about living style. If you see hinduism as a religion it will look like one. But when you start digging this beautiful source of knowledge you will find every point in each of ved, purana, upnishad, mahabharta, ramayana. Teaches us how to live life and at some point you will find its not a religion its a formula to life.
This is all about hinduism.
Hinduism means life itself.

Problems does not matter in hinduism, we means humans are the one who creates problem and the only thing which hinduism teaches is self-realisation. 
If everyone will attain self realisation then there will be no problem at all.