# How to reverse death?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

This question refers to the link [Does Hinduism offer solution for each and every problem of human life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/does-hinduism-offer-solution-for-each-and-every-problem-of-human-life)

It appears Hinduism offer solution or at least a path to find a solution. So is there any known way to give the "life" back to someone dead? It appears somewhere in Mahabharata it is mentioned that Krishna gave back life to someone dead. Is it true?

Comment: One can give life to death through the use of MritaSanjivani Vidya, through use of Amrita etc ... Krishna in Mahabharata gave life to Parikshit through the power of his truth...

Comment: Why do u treat death as a "problem"?

Comment: @Rickross It is not death a problem: it is that "unknown: so is a problem.

Comment: also Savitri brought her husband Satyavan back from Yama's clutches by her pativrata and dharma-gyaan

Comment: @Creator Do you want answer from Mahabharata only?

Comment: @hanugm any reasonable answer is good.

Comment: @Creator do you want such example from scripture or the procedure of reversing death also...

Comment: @hanugm sure, I would like to now your views

Comment: @hanugm, what happened?

Comment: @hanugm mann you are someone, with all those questions,,, become silent. LOL

Comment: @Creator I know examples from scriptures but don't know procedure from scripture...

Comment: @hanugm I did not understand what you mean by "examples from scriptures"? Would you explain a bit please?

Comment: @Creator I mean **bringing back to life (example)** is mentioned in scriptures. But I never see ***how to bring back (procedure)** till now.

Answer (score 2):

> So is there any known way to give the "life" back to someone dead?

**Yes**, there is a way to give back the life of some dead person according to Hindu scriptures. The name of such vidya is Sanjivani (re-vivification). Mentions about Sanjivani are mentioned in many Hindu scriptures.

[Shukra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukra), teacher of Asuras, is a master of Sanjivani vidya and he used it to bring back to life many dead people.

> It appears somewhere in Mahabharata it is mentioned that Krishna gave
> back life to someone dead. Is it true?

It is mentioned in Mahabharata that Sukra gave back life to many dead asuras and Kacha using Sanjivini. Similarly, Kacha gave back life to dead Sukra using Sanjivini (gained from Sukra). I am not sure whether Krishna used Sanjivini anywhere.

[Section 73 of Sambhava Parva of Adi Parva of the Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01077.htm) has mentioned Sanjivani vidya several times

> "Between the celestials and the Asuras, there happened, of yore,
> frequent encounters for the sovereignty of the three worlds with
> everything in them. The gods, then, from desire of victory, installed
> the son of Angiras (Vrihaspati) as their priest to conduct their
> sacrifices; while their opponents installed the learned Usanas as
> their priest for the same purpose. And between those two Brahmanas
> there are always much boastful rivalry. **Those Danavas assembled for
> encounter that were slain by the gods *were all revived by the seer
> Sukra by the power of his knowledge. And then starting again, into
> life,--these fought with the gods*. The Asuras also slew on the field
> of battle many of the celestials. But the open-minded Vrihaspati could
> not revive them, *because he knew not the science called Sanjivani
> (re-vivification)* which Kavya endued with great energy knew so well.**
> And the gods were, therefore, in great sorrow. And the gods, in great
> anxiety of heart and entertaining a fear of the learned Usanas, then
> went to Kacha, the eldest son of Vrihaspati, and spoke unto him,
> saying, 'We pay court to thee, be kind to us and do us a service that
> we regard as very great. That knowledge which resides in Sukra, that
> Brahmana of immeasurable prowess, make thy own as soon as thou canst.
> Thou shalt find the Brahmana in the court of Vrishaparvan. He always
> protects the Danavas but never us, their opponents.............
>
> **"Sukra hearing this said, I will revive him by saying, 'Let this one
> come.' Then having recourse to the science of reviving the dead, Sukra
> summoned Kacha. And summoned by his preceptor, Kacha appeared before
> him in the gladness of heart tearing by virtue of his preceptor's
> science the bodies of the wolves (that had devoured him)**. And asked
> about the cause of his delay, he thus spoke unto Bhargava's daughter.
> Indeed, asked by that Brahman's daughter, he told her, 'I was dead. O
> thou of pure manners, burdened with sacrificial fuel, Kusa grass, and
> logs of wood, I was coming towards our abode. I sat under a banian
> tree. The kine also, having been brought together, were staying under
> the shade of that same banian tree. The Asuras, beholding me, asked
> 'Who art thou?' They heard me answer, '**I am the son of Vrihaspati.' As
> soon as I said this, the Danavas slew me, and hacking my body into
> pieces gave my remains to jackals and wolves. And they then went home
> in the gladness of heart. *O amiable one, summoned by the high-souled
> Bhargava, I after all come before thee fully revived***.'
>
> "On another occasion, asked by Devayani, the Brahmana Kacha went into
> the woods. And as he was roving about for gathering flowers, the
> Danavas beheld him. They again slew him, and pounding him into a paste
> they mixed it with the water of the ocean. Finding him long still (in
> coming), the maiden again represented the matter unto her father.
> **And summoned again by the Brahmana with the aid of his science, Kacha appearing before his preceptor and his daughter told everything
> as it had happened**. Then slaying him for the third time and burning
> him and reducing him to ashes, the Asuras gave those ashes to the
> preceptor himself, mixing them with his wine. And Devayani again spoke
> unto her father, saying, 'O father, Kacha was sent to gather flowers.
> But he is not to be seen. It is plain he hath been lost, or has died.
> I tell thee truly, I would not live without
> him.'.....................
>
> Vaisampayana continued, '**Receiving the
> science imparted to him by his preceptor the handsome Kacha, ripped
> open his stomach, came out like the moon at evening on the fifteenth
> day of the bright fort-night. And beholding the remains of his
> preceptor lying like a heap of penances, Kacha revived him, aided by
> the science he had learned**...........

You can also read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35398/661) answer for one more instance of using Sanjivani by the same Shukracharya from Garga Samhita.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous incidents where spiritually advanced Saints , Monks and Yogis have given life back to dead people.

There are also some people who have come back from Yamapuri or astral plane of Yamraj as their life was mistakenly taken by Yamaduts.

Let's speak about the second type first.... 
My Guru says his grandma was mistakenly carried to Yama by Yamaduts. She was a spiritual lady and somehow knew that she should not die like that as she used to chant Gurumantra her entire life. She firmly asked Yama about if there is a mistake. Yama checked it and they found that some other lady who's husband had same name as that of my Guru's grandfather had to be carried and not her. So they immediately sent her back she woke up and came back from crematorium walking on her own.
One can find numerous such examples over internet.

Saint Tulsidas, Ramdas and many others have given the life back to dead people. Few such stories are there.

I was told by a Fakir that when these Saints give life back to people, they do not break the Karmik Law. Instead by their strong will power and power of union with God  they grab some of the years of the dead person's next life and attach them to life span of the person's present life to extend it.

If by some other mean one can do that then he can reverse the death of a person...

Hinduism is full of such mystry that the more you delve deep into it you find that it is even deeper.....

Well I do not have any proof for what I wrote here as these things were just told.

If I get any stuff related to it over internet  I will definitely put it as a reference.